# Закругленные края в BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet

Как правильно сделать закругленные края в BottomSheetDialogFragment? Применил:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ripple android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/button_buttom_navigation_color_activity"/>
                <corners
                    android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
                    android:topRightRadius="25dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </ripple>
</inset>
```

Но получил слишком темный цвет в пустых закругленных местах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе наследуемом от BottomSheetDialogFragment()

```
override fun getTheme() = R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme
```

В Theme

```
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bottom_sheet_background</item>
</style>
```

bottom_sheet_background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
        android:topRightRadius="12dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: А можно управлять затемнением в AppBottomSheetDialog? Например, затемнение основного окна сделать темнее.

Comment: @garik01 вот это кажется то что нужно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257332/custom-screen-dim-with-dialog